# my images are coming out with bad quality after downloading when i set them to the image view

Tags: android, parsing, listview, bitmap, imageview

the image quality in my listview is bad and keeps repeating the image in each list view. 
this is my image loader class

```
package com.ghost.app;

public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;

public ImageLoader(Context context) {
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launchers;

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    // from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;

        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if (bitmap != null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}

}
```

and i need the images to have rounded corners

this is the lazy adapter

`public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle); // username
    TextView desc = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc); // post
    TextView time = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvdate); // time
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> post = new HashMap<String, String>();
    post = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(post.get("username"));
    desc.setText(post.get("post"));
    time.setText(post.get("timestamp"));
    //imageLoader.DisplayImage(post.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

}`

Comment: How to call this ImageLoader class for display image??

Comment: this is the lazy adapter

Comment: Show your code here...!!

Comment: the lazy adapter code is above

Answer (score 1):

In your ImageLoader class , you have given 100 as required size. increase it for better image.

in this line

```
final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;
```

make it 320 or 480

Comment: i did that and it didnt have any effect

Comment: You are caching the image. So if the image is cached  it will not download. So uninstall the app then change the REQUIRED_SIZE. Hope it will work.